# How to wrap spark streaming output in array brackets?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Spark: `2.3.0` Scala: `2.11.12`

I'm using the spark structure streaming to stream from a kafka topic and output the result to another kafka topic.

```
val mySchema = StructType(StructField("foo", StringType, true) :: Nil)
```

Input data `[{"foo":"bar"}]`

When I use the `select(from_json(col(A), mySchema))` method it parses the object from inside the array and places it in my schema.

What I'm trying to do, is at the end of my filtering dataFrame transformations, to wrap `mySchema` in an array so the output looks the same: `[{"foo":"bar"}]`

However, I can only get the resulting `Dataframe` to output without the array brackets: `{"foo":"bar"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-define your schema since you want the input to be treated as an Array of `struct` types i.e. `array<struct<foo:string>>`

```
val mySchema = ArrayType(StructType(Seq(StructField("foo", StringType, true))),true)
val target = df.select(from_json(col("A"), mySchema).alias("A"))

target.printSchema
//root
// |-- A: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- foo: string (nullable = true)

target.select(to_json($"A")).show
//+----------------+
//|structstojson(A)|
//+----------------+
//| [{"foo":"bar"}]|
//+----------------+
```

Comment: Ah, so simple! I tried a bunch of other things, but not this. Thank you so much!